# c++ declaration of variable that text values only. Am using codeblock for compilation

Tags: c++

Please I want to declare a c++ variable 'choice' that will accept text input only and not int value.I have tried string and char but it still allows for input of int value and etc from users. thanks

Comment: There is no automatically restricted free text input facility in the standard library. Use a `std::wstring` (or just `std::string` if yon't care about both portability and international character support). Check the inputted value. If it's ungood, inform the user and offer the possibility of trying again.

Comment: Either using existing functions to input as a text string and remove the numeric items or get each character individually.

Comment: Explain more about what you mean by "text input only and not int value". Can they type "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue" ?

Answer (score 1):

A std::string will not accept an int value. Inputting 123 to the command line will set the string to the characters '1', '2', and '3'. Ex.

```
std::string st;
cin >> st;
// cin is given "123".
```

If you want, you can always loop through the entire string and check if any characters are numbers (or if all are numbers if that's what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions to validate the input, [c++ reagular expressions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/).